# MySQL Date in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains date (Field Type: Date and Date Format: %Y-%m-%d) as a field. I need to select all the rows from the table for all the years whose date is not between Dec 3rd and Dec 24th.

The table contains month and day as a separate fields.

The result can be obtained by using the following query:

```
select * from mytable where date not in (select date from mytable where month=12 and day between 3 and 24);
```

But i m trying to get the result in a single query like the below one but it gave empty rows:

```
select * from mytable where date not between '%Y-12-03' and '%Y-12-24';
```

Can it be done in a single query like the above one?

Comment: Are you really looking for a literal `%Y`?

Comment: Try `WHERE MONTH(date) = 12 AND DAY(date) BETWEEN 3 AND 24`.  Or rather... `NOT`... that.

Comment: Why do you have separate column for month and day?

Comment: You are correct @STTLCU in raising this question. This is duplication, a "dangerous" violation of 1NF.

Comment: @STT LCU: I have a data warehouse (not DataBase). So to get the results faster, i have added those fields

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I m trying to improve the performance of the query (avoiding the sub query). Not exactly same as %Y but similar logic to that. I tried %Y because % can be used in string literal comparison.

Comment: `%Y` is a format code used by functions like `STR_TO_DATE()` or `DATE_FORMAT()`. It doesn't have any special meaning anywhere else!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE MONTH(`date`) <> 12
  OR DAY(`date`) NOT BETWEEN 3 AND 24
;
```

This will give you every row that meets the requirements. I'm sure someone has a faster way of doing this, since this will ignore all indexes and will likely be slow on a large dataset, but it does work and return the data you require, so if no-one can suggest an improvement this will answer your question.

Comment: Thanks scragar. Good query! There is a tricky part in this query. If we change the order of condition (first put day condition and then month condition), it will not give the expected result.

Comment: We will not get the expected result If we write the query like this, SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DAY(`date`) NOT BETWEEN 3 AND 24 OR MONTH(`date`) <> 12;

Comment: It's working on my tests, do you have any examples of dates that are returning when they shouldn't? @Saravanan

Comment: Consider a table, which contains all dates from Jan 1st 2000 to Dec 31st 2020 sequentially.

Comment: I m sorry. I misunderstood the query. It will work fine even if we change the order. @scragar